# django admin and models

Tags: django, model

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dp74K.png)

Guys I hope all of you are doing great,I have a problem in django3,I have been given a problem and I have to solve it ,I have tried it but not able to solve this,see the image I have given link,

<----question starts here
This list of help1, help2,... gets stored in a database table. You could do a first version of models.py and enable the admin interface for it.

----->question ends here

Can anyone give me a idea?or how to do it or in more simpler words?any ideas or suggestions is appreciated

Comment: Hey, I'd recommend you watch this tutorial on how to do it, this is how I've learned Django: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aHC3uTkT9r8

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really understand what you mean but I think you need to create another model, let's call it `Help`. After created the `Help` model you can use it as foreignkey inside your old model.

models.py

```py
# new model for help types
class HelpType(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.type

# old model
class OldModel(models.Model):
    # other fields
    help_type = models.ForeignKey(HelpType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

admin.py

```py
# register it to admin panel
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import HelpType

admin.site.register(HelpType)
```

Now you can create all help types in admin panel and then when you create your OldModel's object all **help types** will be listed as drop down in `help_type` field